Vuetify 2: search bar doesn't filter database
I want to implement a basic search bar for a datatable and I implemented the way the documentation recommends, but it doesn't work. Any guesses on what I need to fix?
<v-row class="ma-2">
  <v-text-field
    v-model="search"
    clearable
    hint="Filtere die Liste nach diesem Begriff."
    label="Filter"
    prepend-icon="mdi-filter"
    single-line
  />
</v-row>
<v-data-table
  class="table-border"
  dense
  disable-pagination
  :headers="headers"
  hide-default-footer
  :items="$store.state.shoes"
  :loading="$store.state.shoes.loading"
  :search="search"
  :server-items-length="$store.state.shoes.totalRows"
  @click:row="clickOnRow"
  @click:away="unselectRow"
>
</v-data-table>


We can only guess with what you provided! Server-items-length prop is a bit sus..

Thank you, that was actually it. I added server-items-length because it's apparently needed for custom sorting of the entries. But I removed it and now the search bar works!
